How to use the scrollLeft inside this code?

let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex)

function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    const slajdovi = document.getElementsByClassName('slajd')
    const točke = document.getElementsByClassName('točka');

    if (n > slajdovi.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slajdovi.length}

    for (let i = 0; i < slajdovi.length; i++) {
        slajdovi[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < točke.length; i++) {
        točke[i].style.backgroundColor = '';
    }

    slajdovi[slideIndex-1].style.display = "flex"; 
    točke[slideIndex-1].style.backgroundColor = "var(--zlatni-tekst-boja)";
}

I tried tying it to the plusSlides() function but nothing worked, also tried replacing it with the line "slajdovi[i].style.display = 'none';" to no avail. Could someone help me? The code is copied off the w3 and currently works as intended but I want it to slide on button click instead of just disappearing and appearing.

 1.Ensure your HTML structure supports horizontal scrolling:-

    <div id="slajdoviContainer" style="overflow-x: hidden; white-space: nowrap; width: 100%; position: relative;">
  <div class="slajd" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%;">Slide 1</div>
  <div class="slajd" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%;">Slide 2</div>
  <div class="slajd" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%;">Slide 3</div>
  <!-- Add more slides as needed -->
</div>

<div class="točke-container">
  <span class="točka" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="točka" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="točka" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  <!-- Add more točke as needed -->
</div>

<button onclick="plusSlides(-1)">Previous</button>
<button onclick="plusSlides(1)">Next</button>



 2.Add CSS for smooth scrolling:-

    #slajdoviContainer {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}



 3.Update your JavaScript to handle horizontal scrolling:-

    let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    const slajdovi = document.getElementsByClassName('slajd');
    const točke = document.getElementsByClassName('točka');
    const slajdoviContainer = document.getElementById('slajdoviContainer');
    const slideWidth = slajdovi[0].offsetWidth; // Assuming all slides have the same width

    if (n > slajdovi.length) { slideIndex = 1; }    
    if (n < 1) { slideIndex = slajdovi.length; }

    // Scroll to the appropriate slide
    slajdoviContainer.scrollLeft = slideWidth * (slideIndex - 1);

    // Update the dots
    for (let i = 0; i < točke.length; i++) {
        točke[i].style.backgroundColor = '';
    }
    točke[slideIndex - 1].style.backgroundColor = "var(--zlatni-tekst-boja)";
}



 - Now, when you click the "Previous" or "Next" buttons, the slides will smoothly scroll horizontally instead of just appearing and disappearing.

